# How to put syslinux on an sd card

Tags: boot, ext4, syslinux

I would like to know how to put syslinux on my sd card and I have tried using extlinux. However, I keep getting the message `Missing Operating System`. Please help me.

Comment: Why you need to syslinux? Do you have embedded ? did you install linux before installing syslinux?

Comment: I am making linux from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `Missing operating system` indicates the BIOS has looked at every device in its list of allowed boot targets, and has not found anything that looks like a legitimate bootloader.

This can mean one of three things: either the installation of the bootloader on the SD card has failed; or the installation was successful but the system BIOS is unable to read a bootloader from a SD card; or the BIOS is not configured to attempt booting from a SD card, even if it could do so.

Not all SD card readers provide boot support: some require a driver to be usable, which restricts them to be useful only after an operating system has been loaded.

If a card reader appears in the OS as a generic USB storage device and is usable without installing any special drivers, the system BIOS might be able to access the reader+SD card combination as a generic USB disk. In this case, you should try setting the BIOS boot settings to "boot from USB".